# Url path to an image not routing as required

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am trying to get a URL path on my (Web)API to route to a controller action.

The path is something like {Base URL}/**action**/integer/**image.jpg**. For some reason, this URL is trying to request a document - **image.jpg** and thus returning a 404 (Not Found). I want it to return the value of **action**.

I have tried the following attribute decorators, but neither seem to work.

- [Route("action/{integer}/{image}.{extension}")]
- [Route("action/{integer}/{image}")]

The methods for this action correspondingly are as follows.

- public HttpResponseMessage action(int integer, string image)
- public HttpResponseMessage action(int integer, string image, string extension)

I have looked at a few other stack overflow solutions, but does not seems to work for this exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried redirecting the call using Katana. But I found I much simpler answer on one of the stack overflow questions.  I can't find the link again - just make the call using the "/" suffix. This ensures what you are parsing in the last URL segment still parses to a string parameter. Then the route attribute does the rest of the magic.

{Base URL}/**action**/integer/**image.jpg**/

Comment: you need to redirect to a page when clicking on an image, right ?

Comment: I think, there is no image named image.jpg, in your server. That's why it returned 404 error response. Make sure that image is displayed on browser.